# moment js 'from' giving weird result

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am getting the `date` from backend like this `[2020, 8, 5, 13, 29, 43, 780000000]` (this is UTC date).

I have to compare this date from current UTC to get the relative time.
In this example current UTC was :- `2020-08-05T15:59:52.514Z`

The expected relative time was 2h 30 mins. I am not sure why the actual response from Moment JS is 16 hrs.

```
const timeInUTC = moment.utc(date)
const currentTimeInUTC = moment.utc(new Date().toISOString())
console.log(timeInUTC.from(currentTimeInUTC))
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide example in more detail, maybe the value of `date`. because checking the log of each with `_a`, the relative time seems right

Comment: date input for timeInUTC is an array @hgb123

Comment: You can just use ```moment.utc()``` to get the current time in UTC. No need to pass a date string,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the format. The date which was input to moment was in array format, while I was calculating current time in UTC in "UTC format".

After making sure both have the same format fixed the issue.

```
const dateInUTCFormat = new Date(
        Date.UTC(date.value[0], date.value[1] - 1, date.value[2], date.value[3], date.value[4], date.value[5])
    )

    const timeInUTC = moment(dateInUTCFormat)
    const currentTimeInUTC = moment.utc()
    console.log(timeInUTC.from(currentTimeInUTC)
```

)